# Get data from mysql and group under categories

Tags: php, mysql

i get data from database with this srtucture

```
Cars   | Category   | 1Days |   3 Days  
-------|--------------|------–--|---------––
Car1   |  Off Road  | 50.00 | 90,00  
Car2   |  Off Road  | 50.00 | 90,00  
Car3   |  Minivan   | 50.00 | 90,00
```

I want to change it to

```
Off Road
Cars   | 1Days |    3 Days  
-------|----------|---––
Car1   |  50.00 | 90,00  
Car2   |   50.00 | 90,00  
Minivan
 Cars   | 1Days |   3 Days  
-------|----------|---––
Car3   |  50.00 | 90,00
```

I want to group tables under categories

Thank you for advance

Comment: Your exact output would probably have to be handled in the PHP code.  Can you include your PHP code?

Comment: I am sory, i can not add code, here is link with code
http://opentoursgeorgia.xyz/test.txt

Comment: That doesn't help your question.  Include the code as text.  If you can't spend 5 minutes formatting your question, why would you expect someone else to spend time answering it?

Comment: My apologize, i am new here, i will try to post formatted code as a text

Comment: What if there was '5 days'?

Answer (score 2):

You will probably have to handle this from your PHP presentation layer.  Here is one approach:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM yourTable ORDER BY category, cars";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$category = NULL;

echo "<table colspan=\"3\">";

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($category != $row["category"]) {
            echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\">" . $row["category"] . "</tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>Cars</td><td>1 Days</td><td>3 Days</td></tr>";
            $category = $row["category"];
        }
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["cars"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["1days"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["3days"] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

The above code uses logic which, upon seeing a not-yet-seen category in the result set, will print two header rows.  The first header row just contains the category, and the second contains the headers for the three columns in your table.

An important note here is that we use `ORDER BY category, cars` in the MySQL query to impose the order we want in the result set data.  Without using `ORDER BY`, our approach might not work.

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen Thank you very mutch, your code did exactly what i wanted